# clang vs gcc - passing non-copyable type to variadic generic lambda

Tags: c++, gcc, lambda, language-lawyer, c++14

[gcc.godbolt.org link](https://godbolt.org/g/HxMq0K)

I've encountered a situation where passing a non-copyable type (by reference) to a variadic generic lambda after a copyable type (by copy) causes a compilation error on `g++` (both on `5.3` and `6.1`) but not on `clang++`.

```
int main()
{
    auto f = [](auto&&...)
    {
    };

    non_copyable nc;

    f(nc); // ok on both compilers
    f(nc, int{}); // ok on both compilers
    f(int{}, nc); // error only on gcc 
}
```

`g++` gives the following error for the `f(int{}, nc)` call:

```
x.cpp: In function ‘void test()’:
x.cpp:19:19: error: use of deleted function ‘non_copyable::non_copyable(const non_copyable&)’
     f(int{}, nc);
                ^
x.cpp:8:5: note: declared here
     non_copyable(const non_copyable&) = delete;
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

It seems that if the first argument is passed by copy, all the other arguments are passed by copy as well. This looks like a bug, because using an hand-written callable object that should be equivalent to the lambda works on both compilers:

```
// should be equivalent to `[](auto&&...){ }`
struct do_nothing
{
    template <typename... Ts>
    constexpr auto operator()(Ts&&...) const noexcept
    {
    }
};

// ...

do_nothing{}(nc); // ok on both compilers
do_nothing{}(nc, int{}); // ok on both compilers
do_nothing{}(int{}, nc); // ok on both compilers
```

There seems to be an inconsistency between callable objects and generic variadic lambdas on `g++`.

Is this a `g++` bug? Or is there something I am missing?

Comment: Actually it should be deduced as a reference. This one works too: `f(int{}, non_copyable{});`.

Comment: Looks like a bug - try filing a bug report?

Comment: @KerrekSB: sure thing - just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything obvious. Filing a report right now

Comment: Reported as [bug #71332](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=71332)

Comment: This is actually a parsing problem. The workaround is to give the pack a name.